# dilation for general measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I know that for the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, it holds that

For $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$,  $$m(A + t) = m(A)$$ and

$$ m(\lambda A) = \lambda^n m(A)$$  for $\lambda > 0.$

Is this true in general for any Borel measure?

Comment: No, take e.g. the dirac measure $\delta_0$ given by $\delta_0(M) = \chi_M (0)$.

Comment: How does one define $\delta_0(\lambda x)$, e.g., $\int \phi(x) d\delta(\lambda x) $?

Comment: Funny thing, if you only require $m(A + t) = m(A)$ for all $A$ Borel and $t \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then $m$ is proportional to the Lebesgue measure so we also have the dilation property. The Lebesgue measure is a  Haar measure for the Lie group $(\mathbb{R}^n, +)$, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure

Comment: We have $\chi_M (x) =1$ if $x \in M$ and $\chi_M (x)=0$ otherwise. This implies $\int f(x) d\delta_0 (x) = f(0)$.

Comment: sorry, I meant to ask how one defines the dilation of a dirac measure.

Comment: You do not need to **define** it. You simply have $\delta_0 (\lambda M) = \chi_{\lambda M} (0) = \chi_{M} (0) = \delta_0 (M)$ for each $\lambda > 0$, because of $0 \in \lambda M \, \Leftrightarrow \, 0 \in M$. Similarly, $\delta_0 (A + t) = \delta_{-t} (A)$, where $\delta_{-t}$ is the dirac measure at $-t$, defined by $\delta_{-t} (A) = \chi_{A}(-t)$.